# What is role of 'type' => 'static' in Magento 2 data patch?

Tags: magento2

Recently I saw Setup/Patch/Data with `'type'  => 'static'`

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'attribute_code',
        [
            'group' => 'General',
            'label' => 'Product Type ID',
            'type'  => 'static',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => \Vendor\Module\Model\Source\Source::class,
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 1,
            'global' => Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'used_in_product_listing' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
        ]
    );
```

How does this static type work and when should I use it?
Thank's for any information))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short details :**

**'type' => 'static'** means that attributes is stored in main eav table. For ex : **position** is stored in `catalog_category_entity` table.

You can see here that attribute created from `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Setup/CategorySetup.php`

Comment: Thank's, for your answer